# Writing a mailbox property to a Variable or text box

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am writing a basic GUI that makes it easier for staff to find current mailbox/calendar rights. Essentially they type the name of the mail box and the user who's permissions they wish to check, and it writes what the permissions are

I have tried two ways and both ran into problems. The first:

```
$Property = get-mailboxpermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User | Format-List AccessRights    if($Property -eq "AccessRights : {FullAccess}")
    $PermissionText.AppendText(($Property))
```

Results with the output:

`"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData....."`

(I have also get the same when simply inputting the get-mailbox command to the append text)

I have also tried instead to convert the access rights property to a variable, then writing that to the text box using if conditions as below code, but that doesn't play nice either

Method:

```
$Property = get-mailboxpermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User | format-list AccessRights
if($Property -eq "AccessRights : {FullAccess}")
    {$PermissionText.AppendText("Full Access")}
if($Property -eq "AccessRights : {ReadAccess}")
    {$PermissionText.AppendText("Read Only")}
```

Output: Nothing whatsoever

in short, I need a way of either outputting just the permissions to the text box, or, making the variable equal something useable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Property = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User | ? {$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess"} 

if($Property)
{
    $PermissionText.AppendText($Property.User.ToString())
}
```

Comment: Its giving me an output, albeit the output is just the username and domain of the mailbox. Definitely on the right track though

Comment: Ah, I have made it work using this with some changes

Comment: $Property = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User | ? {$_.AccessRights}
$PermissionText.AppendText($Permission.AccessRights)

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou @Avshalom i figured it from your idea:

```
$Property = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User | ? {$_.AccessRights}
$PermissionText.AppendText($Permission.AccessRights)
```